# I would like you to send the new information (as JSON) to the PHP page asynchronously. PHP receives the new data and updates the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

My code not updated in database asynchronously, I should click "update" button to update it, the function should work when the  user  use ‘Update’  mode,  he can  edit  the   information  then  inform  the  page  that  they  finished editing .. please help
Html:

```
<form method="POST" action="EditCourse.php?id=<?php echo $courseid ?>" id="form">
<fieldset> <legend> Course Information</legend>
Course Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo $name?>" onblur="validate(this.value)" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]*" ><br>
 Course Field: <input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="<?php echo $fied?>"  pattern="[A-Za-z\s]*"><br>
 Course Description:<textarea name="description" rows="8" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*"  oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter character only. ')" cols="80"> <?php echo $des ?></textarea><br>
 Course Image:<input type="file" name="Book_cover"  id="Book_cover"><br>
 <button class="button">UPDATE</button>
 <div id="message"></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Java script:

```
  function validate(title){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }};
xhttp.open("POST", "EditCourse.php?courseid=17627", true);
 xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 xhttp.send("title="+title);
 }
```

PHP:

```
 $ID3=$_GET['id'];
  $title3=$_POST['title'];
 $pic = base64_encode(file_get_contents(addslashes($pic)));
$sqlipdate="UPDATE Course SET Name='$title3' WHERE ID='$ID3'";

 $result =mysqli_query($connection,$sqlipdate);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
echo "<span>The update is saved</span>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<span>error1</span>";
  }
```

Comment: This is open to sql injection. Use a prepared statement if you don't want your database to suddenly go *Poof!*

Answer (score 0):

Since `UPDATE` query does not return a result set, `mysqli_num_rows($result)` is always 0.

From [PHP doc on mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You might want to look into [mysqli_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.

Comment: I try it but nothing change:(

Comment: My problem is I want to update table without load page or click update button

Comment: The button will do the form action; all things being equal it will go to php, and do the update, and be off the page. The function is (should be) called when user leaves the Course Title input. You need to use the debugger in browser developer tools to see what's happening with the js.

Comment: Do you know how to use json in this case?

Comment: I thought the question was "why is my database not getting updated?" based on this statement "_My code not updated in database asynchronously_". If that is not the case, then I suggest you make clarifications in the post, and I will delete the answer.